# justify-content: center is not working with grid

Tags: html, css

I am learning CSS grid. While practicing I got an issue. `justify-content: center` is not centering  `section-3-nav` div.

Here is my code:

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    text-decoration: none;
    list-style: none;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}
.container {
    width: 85%;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 3rem 0;
}
.container > .constant {
    display: grid;
    justify-items: center;
}
.box-top-title > h1 {
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-top: 2rem;
}
.box-top-subtitle > p {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #a8b9c0;
    margin: 0.5rem 0;
    font-size: 15px;
}
.box-top-hr > hr {
    width: 250px;
    background-color: #00c6bf;
    border-width: 0;
    height: 1.5px;
}
.section-3 {
    background: #eff7fa;
    width: 100%;
}
.section-3 > .container > .section-3-nav {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);
    justify-content: center;
    margin: 3rem 0;
    width: 50%;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
.section-3 > .container > .section-3-nav a {
    transition: 0.5s;
}
.section-3 > .container > .section-3-nav a:hover {
    background: #ff3150;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="section-3">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="constant">
                <div class="box-top-img"><img src="./images/2-Bondi---PSD-Landing-Page.png" alt=""></div>
                <div class="box-top-title"><h1>We Make This</h1></div>
                <div class="box-top-subtitle"><p>Prepare to be amazed</p></div>
                <div class="box-top-hr"><hr></div>
            </div>
            <div class="section-3-nav">
                <div><a href="#">All</a></div>
                <div><a href="#">Design</a></div>
                <div><a href="#">Code</a></div>
                <div><a href="#">Photography</a></div>
                <div><a href="#">Apps</a></div>
            </div>
            <div class="section-3-stuffs">
                
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Where is the problem with the code? Where to fix and what to fix?

It will be very helpful for me if you help to solve the problem.

Thank you.

Comment: Your grid is the same size as your grid items so technically they are centered. If you add a background colour to that div, you can see how big your grid is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am presuming you want to center the div to the page itself.

Try adding:

```
   margin: auto;
```

It would center the div when used with `width: 50%;` Else, it would stretch and center.

Comment: Thank you so much sir.

Comment: This does not answer the question, it does not use CSS grid.

Answer (score 3):

Usually you should think about positioning an element from the perspective of the parent element, not the element itself.

If you want to center the `section-3-nav` element as part of a grid layout, you have to either

1. Do it in the parent element (`.container`) with `justify-content: center` or
2. Use `justify-self: center` in the element itself

In both cases, the parent element (`.container`) has to use `display: grid`, too.

Answer (score 1):

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    text-decoration: none;
    list-style: none;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}
.container {
    width: 85%;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 3rem 0;
}
.container > .constant {
    display: grid;
    justify-items: center;
}
.box-top-title > h1 {
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-top: 2rem;
}
.box-top-subtitle > p {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #a8b9c0;
    margin: 0.5rem 0;
    font-size: 15px;
}
.box-top-hr > hr {
    width: 250px;
    background-color: #00c6bf;
    border-width: 0;
    height: 1.5px;
}
.section-3 {
    background: #eff7fa;
    width: 100%;
}
.section-3 > .container > .section-3-nav {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);
    text-align: center;
    margin: 3rem 0;
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
.section-3 > .container > .section-3-nav a {
    transition: 0.5s;
}
.section-3 > .container > .section-3-nav a:hover {
    background: #ff3150;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="section-3">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="constant">
                <div class="box-top-img"><img src="./images/2-Bondi---PSD-Landing-Page.png" alt=""></div>
                <div class="box-top-title"><h1>We Make This</h1></div>
                <div class="box-top-subtitle"><p>Prepare to be amazed</p></div>
                <div class="box-top-hr"><hr></div>
            </div>
            <div class="section-3-nav">
                <div><a href="#">All</a></div>
                <div><a href="#">Design</a></div>
                <div><a href="#">Code</a></div>
                <div><a href="#">Photography</a></div>
                <div><a href="#">Apps</a></div>
            </div>
            <div class="section-3-stuffs">
                
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Try this text-align:center;   &  width:100%

Comment: Maybe add an explanation why this works and what the issue is?